# Append selected form into table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code example below:

```
  <label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
    <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        {% for p in tickers %}
            <option value="{{ p.ticker_name }}">
                {{ p.ticker_name }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
    <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id="fin_ratio">
        {% for f in fin_ratio %}
            <option value="">
                {{ f.ratio_code }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <label for="">Select Item:  </label>
    <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id="item_code">
        {% for i in items %}
            <option value="">
                {{ i.item_code }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

<div class="col-md-12" style="">
        <table class="table table-responsive" style="width: 100%" id="myTable">
            <thead>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

When I select the value in select form I want to append it to the first column and select next in other it also append into the table. I will try this but it append all to the table.

```
$(document).on('change', '#selected', function () {
            var ticker = $( "#selected" ).val();
            var ratio = $( "#fin_ratio" ).val();
            alert(ratio);
            var item = $("#item_code").val();
            var tr = (
                  '<tr>' +
                    '<td>'+ ticker +'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+ ratio+'</td>'+
                    '<td>' + item + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>'
                );
```

{#                alert(ticker);#}
                $('#myTable').append(tr);

How can I use jQuery to append 3 different selected forms into each next column in table body?

Comment: The HTML you've shown doesn't seem entirely relevant to the problem you've described (there's no sign of '3 forms' and there are no columns). However http://api.jquery.com/append is what you need

Comment: Please provide HTML of your form atleast selector, And is table already available on the page or you want it to be added as well.

Comment: Do you want to display the values of selected select boxes in the corresponding column in that particular row where this select boxes exists?

Comment: @amitwadhwani: I will add the code more clearly, you may have any idea for me. Thanks

Comment: @gjijo: Exactly, I will add more code, so you may help me in this situation. Thanks.

Comment: @amitwadhwani: I will provide more my code already, so you can help me for so far.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I get some mistake in my post, I already edit again more clearly. Let me know some good things in my code. On the frontend, I am not well. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify because right now we have to guess.... More details are needed...

Comment: @coder_1432: I have 3 selected form, and when I choose first value in select options, I want to put in first <td> tag, next when I choose the second, it also added into second <td> tag in table. How can I use jQuery to get those value into each row of table.

Comment: @ThoLeHoang : I've posted an answer to match your requirement. But not sure whether I got you right. So please check.

Comment: @gjijo: Yes, exactly that I hope, Thanks a lot. One more questions in this situation, if I only get the value in each form by using jQuery, how can I do that because I want to get those value for using ajax request to the server to get the data on the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your select boxes are in same table:

```js
// Finding index of columns
var tickerColumnIndex = $('table tr th:contains(Ticker)').index();
var ratioColumnIndex = $('table tr th:contains(Ratio)').index();
var itemColumnIndex = $('table tr th:contains(Item)').index();

// Change event for Ticker
$(document).on('change', '#selected', function() {
  var txt = $('#selected option:selected').text();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(tickerColumnIndex).text(txt);
});

// Change event for Ratio
$(document).on('change', '#fin_ratio', function() {
  var index = $('table tr th:contains(Ratio)').index();
  var txt = $('#fin_ratio option:selected').text();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(ratioColumnIndex).text(txt);
});

// Change event for Item
$(document).on('change', '#item_code', function() {
  var index = $('table tr th:contains(Item)').index();
  var txt = $('#item_code option:selected').text();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(itemColumnIndex).text(txt);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr th,
table tr td {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Ticker</th>
      <th>Ratio</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='fin_ratio'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Item:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='item_code'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 3</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='fin_ratio'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Item:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='item_code'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 3</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='fin_ratio'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 3</option>
    </select>
        <br />
        <label for="">Select Item:  </label>
        <select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='item_code'>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 3</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If your select box is outside the table:

```js
// Finding index of columns
var tickerColumnIndex = $('.tbl-display tr th:contains(Ticker)').index();
var ratioColumnIndex = $('.tbl-display tr th:contains(Ratio)').index();
var itemColumnIndex = $('.tbl-display tr th:contains(Item)').index();

// Change event for Ticker
$(document).on('change', '#selected', function() {
  var txt = $('#selected option:selected').text();
  $('.tbl-display tbody tr:first').find('td').eq(tickerColumnIndex).text(txt);
});

// Change event for Ratio
$(document).on('change', '#fin_ratio', function() {
  var index = $('table tr th:contains(Ratio)').index();
  var txt = $('#fin_ratio option:selected').text();
  $('.tbl-display tbody tr:first').find('td').eq(ratioColumnIndex).text(txt);
});

// Change event for Item
$(document).on('change', '#item_code', function() {
  var index = $('table tr th:contains(Item)').index();
  var txt = $('#item_code option:selected').text();
  $('.tbl-display tbody tr:first').find('td').eq(itemColumnIndex).text(txt);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr th,
table tr td {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 3</option>
    </select>
<br />
<label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='fin_ratio'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ratio 3</option>
    </select>
<br />
<label for="">Select Item:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='item_code'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Item 3</option>
    </select>

<table class="tbl-display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticker</th>
      <th>Ratio</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Adding multiple rows to table using Add & Edit button.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn_Add', function() {
  var Tickertxt = $('#selected option:selected').text();
  var Ratiotxt = $('#fin_ratio option:selected').text();
  var Itemtxt = $('#item_code option:selected').text();

  var Tickerval = $('#selected option:selected').val();
  var Ratioval = $('#fin_ratio option:selected').val();
  var Itemval = $('#item_code option:selected').val();
  var tr = $('<tr>');
  tr.append($('<td val="' + Tickerval + '">' + Tickertxt + '</td>'));
  tr.append($('<td val="' + Ratioval + '">' + Ratiotxt + '</td>'));
  tr.append($('<td val="' + Itemval + '">' + Itemtxt + '</td>'));
  tr.append($('<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" id="btn_Edit" /></td>'));
  $('table tbody').append(tr);

  $('#selected').val('');
  $('#fin_ratio').val('');
  $('#item_code').val('');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn_Edit', function() {
  var currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var indx = $(currentTr).prop('index');
  var TickerVal = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(0).attr('val');
  var RatioVal = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(1).attr('val');
  var ItemVal = $(currentTr).find('td').eq(2).attr('val');
  $('#selected').val(TickerVal);
  $('#fin_ratio').val(RatioVal);
  $('#item_code').val(ItemVal);
  currentTr.remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table tr th,
table tr td {
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Select Ticker:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='selected'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ticker1">Ticker 1</option>
        <option value="Ticker2">Ticker 2</option>
        <option value="Ticker3">Ticker 3</option>
    </select>
<br />
<label for="">Select Ratio:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='fin_ratio'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Ratio1">Ratio 1</option>
        <option value="Ratio2">Ratio 2</option>
        <option value="Ratio3">Ratio 3</option>
    </select>
<br />
<label for="">Select Item:  </label>
<select class="form-control" style="display: inline" id='item_code'>
        <option>--select--</option>
        <option value="Item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Item3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="btn_Add" />
<table class="tbl-display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticker</th>
      <th>Ratio</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helping, let me try again.

Comment: One more questions in this situation, if I only get the value in each form by using jQuery, how can I do that because I want to get those value for using ajax request to the server to get the data on the server-side.

Comment: $('#fin_ratio option:selected').text(); will give the text and $('#fin_ratio option:selected').val(); will give its value.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting well.

Comment: Your code work perfectly when I try it, but how I can append in the next td tag for 3 other value in my table.

Comment: Can you please explain..Do you mean , you need to add more td's apart from Ticker, Ratio and Item. Or another row?

Comment: Yes, I want to add more in the table, your code only works one time and end. Thanks

Comment: @ThoLeHoang: Since you are having only single set of select boxes(), and a table, How will you know, whether to add a new row or change the value in an already added row while changing the selected value of a select box? Do you have an 'Add button' for adding selected value to select boxes to grid?

Comment: Wow, thank you sincerely. You make it very clearly for me. I learn a lot from my practice.